# Combining or substituting multiple similar overloads

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I have structure "foo" with many members, one of which (double bar) is accessed several times in basic operations. So instead of writing, for example:

```
double a=foo.bar+3;
double b=foo.bar*5;
bool c=foo.bar==2;
```

I wanted to write:

```
double a=foo+3;
double b=foo*5;
bool c=foo==2;
```

One approach would be overloading all desired operators in free functions:

```
template< class T>
double operator@(foo a,T b){
    return a.bar@b;
}
template< class T>
double operator@(T b,foo a){
    return a.bar@b;
}
```

I would then have to copy and paste this snippet and substitute @ by +, *, == and other operations I wanted.

Is there a better (more readable, less repetitive, shorter and/or safer) way to do it ? For instance, using templates or guiding the compiler to try substituting "foo" by "foo.bar" whenever it does not find a match for a function involving "foo".

Comment: Aside: `^` is not the exponentiation operator in C++. (and for precedence reasons, it is a bad idea to provide an overload that acts like exponentiation)

Comment: Am I missing something obvious here? `double tmp = foo.bar; double a = tmp + 3; double b = tmp * 3; …`

Comment: @Konrad That is indeed possible, but I have many such structures in rather long equations and then would have to manage several temporary variables. Also, in the context, preserving their names improves readability ( say, using F for a force, m for mass and a for acceleration to get F=m*a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you simply want to get back a `double` (rather than whatever `foo` is) you could just define a conversion operator to `double`:

```
struct foo {
    double bar;
    operator double() const { return this->bar; }
};
```